# Eclipse says I have missing include directives but code still compiles c++

Tags: c++, eclipse, include, eclipse-cdt

So i am having a problem with eclipse. It's not so much of a problem as it is an annoyance. I have a c++ project in eclipse and when I include standard libraries it says symbol could not be resolved. When I compile it everything is fine and works and compiles correctly. I dont see why eclipse doesn't recongize my include directives. Any advice would help thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What's likely happening is that your include directives are incorrect but your compiler is linking against the standard libraries by default. If your functions happen to match symbols that are defined in those libraries, your code will *probably* work but you may encounter strange, undefined behavior.

Comment: its happening to these includes
#include <iostream>  //unresolved inclusion
using std::cout; //symbol could not be resolved

Answer (score 0):

The most possibility is you updated your c/c++ compiler. Eclipse will add newly discovered paths into include list. But never remove old ones.

Try remove folder .metadata in your workspace, and restart eclipse again.

The whole world will be clean & clear again.

cheer up